# Deploying Java Application on Windows System

Tags: java, swing, batch-file, user-interface, deployment

I have created a Client-Server System using Sockets to send files over same network.
Now I have created their respective JARs. I have placed the option in context menu using regedit in my Windows 8

[image: Preview]

I use Batch script to direct argument from this context menu to Jar file. Here I am failing.
I am using this script to direct arguments

[image: Batch Script]

My Jar file recieves nothing as argument and intended purpose of placing it in context menu fails.

Comment: BTW - those screenshots make me think it is based on Swing.  I added the tag.  Please [change it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21107433/edit) if incorrect, to identify which GUI toolkit is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write:

```
java -jar client.jar %1
```

or

```
java -jar client.jar %*
```

Anyways, remove `""`

Answer (score 2):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, **file associations,** automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or locale, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Launching a rich client app. using a batch script or from the command line seems so ..last millennium.